# Limit Of, Limit To

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

It seems that the noun "*limit*" could be followed by both "*to*" and "*of*", even for the same sense (1a) in some [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/limit):

> --He has reached the ***limit of*** his endurance.
>   --There are ***limits to*** what I can put up with from him!

Do native speakers know when to use "*to*" and "*of*"?

Comment: This native speaker came here looking for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do.  Looking at it, it's not really obvious why, though.  The rule (to which I can think of some exceptions) is that we use *of* with *the*, and *to* with *a*.  Like this:

> There is a limit to his endurance.
> He has reached the limit of his endurance.

I can't think of a circumstance in which you would go wrong using this rule.   Still, you might see something like this:

> The limit to what I'm willing to spend is $100.

The reason that you might see this is that it could imply this:

> There is a limit to what I'm willing to spend.  The limit to what I'm willing to spend is $100.

So, if you are talking about "the limit" in reference to "a limit" that has been stated or implied, then you might use *to* instead of *of*.

Now, here you would generally use *of*:

> $100 is the limit of what I'm willing to spend.

(Edit: six years later, I believe I have changed my mind. In this case, either *of* or *to* sounds ok. That's prepositions for you.)

So, while there might be some exceptions to the rule, you can still apply it in those situations without going wrong.

Comment: This is an interesting one. I know exactly when to use **of** vs. **to**, but I can't think of a good way to explain how I know this.

Comment: One clue might be  in `He has reached the limit`. No matter what I say after that, I already know that I'm going to say "of"

Comment: Some good examples, but what about:
- "You must not attend as an invividual party that exceeds the limit on group sizes due to current Covid-19 restrictions."
I think "on" is correct here but I am not 100% sure and English is my 1st language.

Comment: @Jake So am I, and I'm not 100% sure either. I think either one might be fine.